# KDE Connect looses pairing once my phone is locked

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, android, kde-connect

My desktop:

```
❯ uname -a
Linux rigel 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

❯ kdeconnect-app --version
kdeconnect.app 1.0
```

My phone is Pixel 3a with Android 12 and KDE Connect 1.19.1 installed from Google Play Store. The network where all this is happening is trusted, meaning that my Phone does not change physical address, moreover it has a static IP.

I have no problems pairing those two and every feature (e.g. file transfer, remote control, etc.) seems to be working fine. The problem is, once I turn the screen on my phone off/on, KDE Connect removes the phone from the list of trusted (paired) devices. I ran `kdeconnect-app` in console and got this output:

```
❯ kdeconnect-app   
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ContextDrawer.qml:79: TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ContextDrawer.qml:79: TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ContextDrawer.qml:79: TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object
kdeconnect.interfaces: Adding missing or previously removed device "a484339f505ceccc"
kdeconnect.interfaces: Adding missing or previously removed device "a484339f505ceccc"
kdeconnect.interfaces: Adding missing or previously removed device "a484339f505ceccc"
kdeconnect.interfaces: Adding missing or previously removed device "a484339f505ceccc"
kdeconnect.interfaces: Adding missing or previously removed device "a484339f505ceccc"
kdeconnect.interfaces: Adding missing or previously removed device "a484339f505ceccc"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ContextDrawer.qml:79: TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ContextDrawer.qml:79: TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object
qrc:/qml/DevicePage.qml:45: TypeError: Type error
qrc:/qml/DevicePage.qml:32: TypeError: Type error
qrc:/qml/DevicePage.qml:134: TypeError: Type error
qrc:/qml/DevicePage.qml:120: TypeError: Type error
qrc:/qml/DevicePage.qml:112: TypeError: Type error
kdeconnect.interfaces: Removed changed device  "a484339f505ceccc"
```

Apparently, something does change when the phone goes back online, but what? I checked whether device config or certificate changes in `~/.config/kdeconnect/trusted_devices`, but it doesn't.

Any ideas what can cause or how to fix this issue?

Comment: Allowing background activity for kde connect app in android may help, but will drain battery quickly

Comment: Didn't find the solution but once I moved from Ubuntu to Arch the problem resolved itself. Since it took no adjustments on my phone, I assume the problem was with KDE.